# How to store encrypted value (for ex- ðçM¸½§J·h°P¥\«ahæ‡i»Uç¹&>9ó?) in a node of xml file

Tags: java, xml, encryption

I am using following code for encryption and decryption (Using AES keys) in java -

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncryptionTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

      String key = "ThisIsASecretKey";
      byte[] ciphertext = encrypt(key, "1234567890123456");
      System.out.println( new String(ciphertext));
      System.out.println("decrypted value:" + (decrypt(key, ciphertext)));

    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static byte[] encrypt(String key, String value)
      throws GeneralSecurityException {

    byte[] raw = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    if (raw.length != 16) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
    }

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,
        new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    return cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
  }

  public static String decrypt(String key, byte[] encrypted)
      throws GeneralSecurityException {

    byte[] raw = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    if (raw.length != 16) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
    }
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,
        new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

    return new String(original, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
  }
}
```

Now I want to store the encrypted value which is returned by this code, in a node of xml file.
As this block of code returns encrypted value as - **ðçM¸½§J·h°P¥\«ahæ‡i»Uç¹&>9ó?**

When I try to store and/or retrieve this value from XML file using Java code then it gives exception.
like - 
**com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence**

Please suggest how to retrieve this type of value from XML file using Java code.

Comment: Encode it to base64 or hexadecimal

Comment: Is the value ðçM¸½§J·h°P¥\«ahæ‡i»Uç¹&>9ó? possible to add/retrieve from xml file using Java code ?